# Downloading multiple Files at the same Time (Multithreading)

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm trying to use multithreading in ruby for heaving a lot of Network-Connections at the same time but I really stuck at the basics.

I tried this:

```
for i in 1..1000 do
  Thread.new{load(i)}
end

def load(i)
  File.open(filePath, "w") do |output|
    open(imageURL) do | input |
      output << input.read
    end
  end
end
```

This is only a part of the Download-Script for showing what I'm doing. At real I first load some HTML, parse it with Nokogiri and so on...

I'm running this script in Terminal with "ruby script.rb" - and nothing - really nothing happened.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks [allot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html)
Chris

Comment: You might be interested in [this article](http://andrey.chernih.me/2014/05/29/downloading-multiple-files-in-ruby-simultaneously/) which compares 3 ways of downloading multiple files simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Your script will immediately exit, because you are not waiting for your threads to finish.

Consider the first example of [this section of the Pickaxe](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_threads.html) - you need to [join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Thread.html#M000811) your threads, in order to actually wait for all of them to finish their jobs.

So you should rather try this:

```
def load(i)
  ...
end

threads = []

for i in 1..1000 do
  threads << Thread.new { load(i) }
end

threads.each { |t| t.join }
```